# Which programming language is recommended for android development? Kotlin OR Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I was developing an android app using ionic framework and planning to convert the app to native. I have read few articles on the internet and still couldn't get a better answer for my question.

Since there are two languages to develop android apps, what would be the recommended language between Java and Kotlin for large scale android app development?

Answer (score 2):

Google is going kotlin-first in its documentation, even saying that you ["Write better Android apps faster with Kotlin"](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/). So you should be using Kotlin. Furthermore Kotlin has some advantages:

- less verbose
- strong interoperability with Java (you can still use java libraries)
- Coroutines ([Improve app performance with Kotlin coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines))

But of course, you will find less tutorial than in Java on certain topics (but it will catch up, the community is growing fast).

### Edit 2021/03/09

Another reason you might consider Kotlin for android is the kotlin extension for gradle which provide auto-completion and an object like approach in configuration files. You can find a few resources [here](https://quickbirdstudios.com/blog/gradle-kotlin-buildsrc-plugin-android/#:%7E:text=%20Kotlin%20and%20the%20buildSrc%20Plugin%20made%20me,apply%20these%20dependencies%20to%20all%20of...%20More%20) and [here](https://gist.github.com/f3401pal/8aa468192a4d35642e20abf9dbd8de4c). Even though this is not pure development keeping a consistent language throughout the all project will make the process easier for everyone.

### Edit 2021/03/18

With the announcement of Jetpack Compose (see [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose)) Beta Google also pushes its use by saying "Jetpack Compose is Android’s modern toolkit for building native UI. It simplifies and accelerates UI development on Android. Quickly bring your app to life with less code, powerful tools, and intuitive Kotlin APIs." and using descriptions as "Less code", "Intuitive", "Accelerate Development" and "Powerful".

### Resources

- [Modern Android development: Android Jetpack, Kotlin, and more (Google I/O 2018)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrMw7MEgADk)
- [Google I/O'19 - Chet Haase Interview on Jetpack Compose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcZqtBy9MT8&t=114s)

Comment: This is opinion based and please put answers like this in comments.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Clément Jean. I also think its better to develop with kotlin. Hope the community will grow and not get stuck at any point.

Comment: You shouldn't be stucked at all because you can still write Java and interract with it so no worries.

Comment: saying `write better android apps faster with kotlin` doesn't mean it's better or worse than java. it's just saying kotlin is an option.

Comment: you are right but it proves that they are going Kotlin-first

Comment: it really doesn't

Comment: All the documentation show kotlin code first and then you can click on java if you really want to code in Java. For me that's a big sign.

Comment: `For me..` which means that it's your opinion, not official from google

Comment: From Chet Haase, Developer Advocate at Google: "Android is becoming increasingly Kotlin-first, with many new JetPack API’s being introduced first for Kotlin developers. We also think that if you have a new project that you’re starting, you should be doing it in Kotlin because, frankly, there’s less to type, less to test and less to maintain."